# how to translate words in app.routing.module.ts in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have angular routing module and I want to get some words from ngx-translate languages in this routing module but I can not, I try this code but it does no work:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '../../auth/auth.guard';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';
import { SubCategoryComponent } from './category/sub-category/sub-category.component';

import { ColorsComponent } from './colors.component';
import { TypographyComponent } from './typography.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: "{{'NameEng' | translate}}"
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'colors'
      },
      {
        path: 'colors',
        component: ColorsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Colors'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'typography',
        component: TypographyComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'Typography'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'category',
        component: CategoryComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'Categories'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'subcategory',
        component: SubCategoryComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'Sub Categories'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ThemeRoutingModule {}
```

I want to get Title data from translateService but it does not work
can you help me friends
thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, I suposse that you're using [CoreUI](https://coreui.io/angular/).

CoreUI doesn't actually support breadcrumbs translation, but you can clone the breadcrumb component and modify it to make it translatable.

This answer is a modified version of the one provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304952/how-to-add-translate-for-the-breadcrumbs-in-coreui-angular).

breadcrumb.component.html
(Note that it'll try to get the translated title and if doesn't exist, it'll show the raw value you used in the `title` key.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<ng-container *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs | async, let last = last">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"
        *ngIf="breadcrumb.label.title && (breadcrumb.url.slice(-1) == '/' || last)"
        [ngClass]="{active: last}">
        <a *ngIf="!last" [routerLink]="breadcrumb.url" >{{ tr[breadcrumb.label.title] != null ? tr[breadcrumb.label.title] : breadcrumb.label.title }}</a>
        <span *ngIf="last" [routerLink]="breadcrumb.url" >{{ tr[breadcrumb.label.title] != null ? tr[breadcrumb.label.title] : breadcrumb.label.title }}</span>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

breadcrumb.component.ts

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Inject, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';
import {TranslationService} from '../../../services/translation.service';


import {BreadcrumbService} from './breadcrumb.service';

function Replace(el: any): any {
    const nativeElement: HTMLElement = el.nativeElement;
    const parentElement: HTMLElement = nativeElement.parentElement;

    // move all children out of the element
    while (nativeElement.firstChild) {
        parentElement.insertBefore(nativeElement.firstChild, nativeElement);
    }

    // remove the empty element(the host)
    parentElement.removeChild(nativeElement);
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-custom-breadcrumb',
    templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html',
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public tr; // servicio de traduccion


    @Input() fixed: boolean;
    breadcrumbs;
    private readonly fixedClass = 'breadcrumb-fixed';

    constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        public service: BreadcrumbService,
        public el: ElementRef,
        private translationService: TranslationService,
    ) {
        this.tr = translationService.getTranslations();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        Replace(this.el);
        this.isFixed(this.fixed);
        this.breadcrumbs = this.service.breadcrumbs;
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, this.fixedClass);
    }

    isFixed(fixed: boolean = this.fixed): void {
        if (fixed) {
            this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, this.fixedClass);
        }
    }
}
```

breadcrumb.service.ts (unchanged)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BreadcrumbService {

    breadcrumbs: Observable<Array<any>>;

    private breadcrumbSubject: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>;

    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

        this.breadcrumbSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(new Array<any>());

        this.breadcrumbs = this.breadcrumbSubject.asObservable();

        this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((event) => {
            const breadcrumbs = [];
            let currentRoute = this.route.root;
            let url = '';
            do {
                const childrenRoutes = currentRoute.children;
                currentRoute = null;
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
                childrenRoutes.forEach(route => {
                    if (route.outlet === 'primary') {
                        const routeSnapshot = route.snapshot;
                        url += '/' + routeSnapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
                        breadcrumbs.push({
                            label: route.snapshot.data,
                            url
                        });
                        currentRoute = route;
                    }
                });
            } while (currentRoute);

            this.breadcrumbSubject.next(Object.assign([], breadcrumbs));

            return breadcrumbs;
        });
    }
}
```

Now, your Translation service should look like this:
translation.service.ts

```
import {Injectable, LOCALE_ID, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})


export class TranslationService {

    private trans_es;
    private trans_en;


    private localeId = '';
    private es = 'es';
    private en = 'en';


    public translatedLabels;

    headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale) {


        this.trans_es = {};
        this.trans_en = {};

        
        this.trans_es['typography'] = 'Tipografía';
        this.trans_en['typography'] = 'Typography';
        this.trans_es['colors'] = 'Colores';
        this.trans_en['colors'] = 'Colors';
       


        if (locale === 'en') {
            const s = JSON.stringify(this.trans_en);
            const c = JSON.parse(s);
            this.translatedLabels = c;
        } else {
            const s = JSON.stringify(this.trans_es);
            const c = JSON.parse(s);
            this.translatedLabels = c;
        }
    }

    public getTranslations() {
        return this.translatedLabels;
    }


}
```

Then on the html where the breadcrumbs is shown:

```
<app-custom-breadcrumb>
        <li class="breadcrumb-menu d-md-down-none">
        </li>
</app-custom-breadcrumb>
```

And finally you can use it on every route like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ColorsComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'colors'
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this dependence : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker

1- install dependence:

```
    ➜   npm i @biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker --save
```

2- import dep and use it:

```
import { marker as _ } from "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker";

import { ColorsComponent } from './colors.component';
import { TypographyComponent } from './typography.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: _("NameEng")
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'colors'
      },
      {
        path: 'colors',
        component: ColorsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Colors'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'typography',
        component: TypographyComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'Typography'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'category',
        component: CategoryComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'Categories'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'subcategory',
        component: SubCategoryComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'Sub Categories'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ThemeRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

The route files are static files, so is the data you specify in it. So Angular template directives and the expression language won't be evaluated in there.

You can instead translate the translation keys at the point where you read the data from the routes, which I guess is something like a header element.

With `ngx-translate`, that would happen either by using the `TranslateService`, and it's [methods](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods) `get` or `instant`, or just assigning the translations keys to a component field, and in the component template use the `translate` pipe the usual way.

Comment: I want to get the title data from ngx-translate, what should I do??  Can explain it with some code example

Comment: @abdulwahid added some pointers about `ngx-translate`. If you want even more details, then I would be basically doing your job. If you really need that, please post how you extract the data from the route, and how you are trying to display it.

Comment: Hi @abdulwahid, do you need any further assistance? Did this answer help with your problem?